# I want to find the word between the quotes and change the position

Tags: python, python-re

My plan is to find the bbb in the text and reposition it after extracting the words enclosed in quotes on both sides

```
text = "'Banana' aaaaa'Tomato' aaaaa'Tomato' aaaaa'Watermelon' aaaaaa 'Apple'bbb 'Banana' aaaa 'Orange' aaaaaa 'Melon' aaaaaa 'Persimmon' aaaaaaa 'Grape'bbb 'Apple' aaaaaa 'Grape' aaaaa'Tomato' aaaaa 'avocado' aaaaa 'watermelon' aaaaa 'apple'bbb 'mango' aaaa' orange' aaaaaa 'melon' aaaaaa 'persimmon' aaaaaaa 'plum' bbb 'tangerine' aaaaaa..."
```

For example, extract'Apple'bbb 'Banana', 'Grape'bbb 'Apple', 'apple'bbb 'mango', 'plum' bbb 'tangerine' from the text above and change the order to 'Banana'bbb 'Apple', 'Apple'bbb 'Grape', 'mango'bbb 'apple ','tangerine' bbb 'plum'

Is to change the text after making the change. So finally

```
text = "'Banana' aaaaa'Tomato' aaaaa'Tomato' aaaaa'Watermelon' aaaaaa 'Banana'bbb 'Apple' aaaa 'Orange' aaaaaa 'Melon' aaaaaa 'Persimmon' aaaaaaa 'Apple'bbb 'Grape' aaaaaa 'Grape' aaaaa'Tomato' aaaaa 'avocado' aaaaa 'watermelon' aaaaa 'mango'bbb 'apple' aaaa' orange' aaaaaa 'melon' aaaaaa 'persimmon' aaaaaaa 'tangerine' bbb 'plum' aaaaaa..."
```

Is to make it like this. What I have done so far is

```
text = "'Banana' aaaaa'Tomato' aaaaa'Tomato' aaaaa'Watermelon' aaaaaa 'Apple'bbb 'Banana' aaaa 'Orange' aaaaaa 'Melon' aaaaaa 'Persimmon' aaaaaaa 'Grape'bbb 'Apple' aaaaaa 'Grape' aaaaa'Tomato' aaaaa 'avocado' aaaaa 'watermelon' aaaaa 'apple'bbb 'mango' aaaa' orange' aaaaaa 'melon' aaaaaa 'persimmon' aaaaaaa 'plum' bbb 'tangerine' aaaaaa..."

p = re.compile(r"'(\S+\s*\S+\s*)bbb\s*'(\S+)'")
string = p.findall(text)

print(string)

a = list(string[0])
a.reverse()

b = list(string[1])
b.reverse()

print(a)
print(b)
```

I even extracted and changed the order, but I don't really know how to replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `re.sub` to achieve this. Also you need to use `\1 \2 \3` and so on. Like this

```
re.sub(r"('\S*\s*\S+\s*')(bbb\s*)('\S+')", r"\3 \2 \1", text)
```

The `\1` and so on are the matches of your regex, as denoted by the parentheses. The second parameter of `re.sub` will construct the result.

Comment: I used it with some modifications, but it was possible to use it. Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to add the modifications as a comment. I will update the answer.